# How to return the attribute i want from server using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I want the value image, name, decription1 and description2 only, i don't want other attribute relate to the subject table. By using volley, can i done that? If anyone can help i will be appreciated.

```html
"SELECT image, name, Description1, Description2 from subject WHERE subjectID = 'S1'
```

Comment: your question, is ambiguos , so you know volley HTTP post request?

Answer (score 0):

> By using volley, can i done that?

No. Volley is a networking library used to fetch data from a server. Controlling *what* you obtain from the server is determined by the server in question and what requests it supports.